# TextView: Fade out + Read More - Expand on click

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textview

I'd like to fade out long Texts after a fixed number of lines in my app like they did it here in this css tutorial:

https://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/

But I have no clue what to google or how I can implement a behaviour likes this. Can anybode help me with some input?

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/event_text_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="28dp"
        android:maxLines="15"
        />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/overlay_textview" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set TextView's maxLines property (or just set the height to some concrete value), put a view with gradient above it and a button. Handle button and gradient visibility form your code.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    button.visibility = View.GONE
    gradientView.visibility = View.GONE
    textView.layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    textView.requestLayout()
}
```

Comment: mh, and how do I expand a TextView clicking on the Button?

Comment: You can set properties of TextView programmatically. I added a code example to the original answer due to inability to format it properly in the comments.

Comment: Look at my edit, I worked it out with a FrameLayout, the problem is, when the Text is to short, the overlay still gets displayed. The other problem is, when I'm working with a fixed value for the TextView, for example 150dp, the overlay doesn't even affect the TextView, so I have to work with a "match_parent" for the TextView